# A proof of $|\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}$
There are various versions of proof of 'there is a bijection from $\N$ to $\N \times \N$.' But only one of them suits my taste: Make a list
$$
\begin{aligned}
&(1,1),\\
&(1,2), (2,1)\\
&(1,3), (2,2),...
\end{aligned}
$$
and index them by $\N = \{1,2,\cdots\}$. The sum of the elements of each pair equals the index of the corresponding layer plus $1$. It provides the key idea, but I feel I need to explicitly show that it really works. Please check if the followings are valid.

First, let us restrict the domain of discourse to natural numbers. I defined a function $f: \N \to \N^2$ with
$$
\forall m :\forall n \le m:f\left(\frac{(m-1)m}{2} + n\right) = (n,m-n+1)
$$
where $m$ is the index for each layer of the list and $n$ is the column index. $(m-1)m/2$ can be thought of as the accumulated number of elements from the first layer and the layer $m-1$.

Now, we have to show $f$ is bijective.

1. (surjective) I am going to show that $\forall a, b: \exists k:f(k) = (a,b)$. Let $n = a$, and $m-n+1 = b$. Then,
   $$
   m = n + b - 1 \ge n
   $$
   Letting $ k = (a + b - 2)(a + b - 1)/2 + a$ shows $f$ is subjective.
2. (uniqueness of $m$ and $n$ for each argument $k$ of $f$) First, we show that
   $$
   \forall k: \exists!m,n: \left(n \le m \land k = \frac{(m-1)m}{2} + n\right)
   $$
   It is easy to show that
   $$
   \left\{\left.\left(\frac{(m-1)m}{2}\right.,\left.\frac{m(m+1)}{2}\right]\cap\N ~\right|~m\in\N \right\}
   $$
   partitions $\N$. Therefore, for arbitrary $k$, there is unique $m$ such that
   $$
   \frac{(m-1)m}{2} < k \le \frac{m(m+1)}{2}
   \text{ or equivalently, }
   0 < k - \frac{(m-1)m}{2} \le m
   $$
   Using the result, let $n = k - {(m-1)m}/{2} $.
3. (injective) It follows from 2) that for each $a, b \in \N$ there is unique $k$ such that $f(k) = (a,b)$.

The proof is a lot verbose, but I could be content only with such details.

Comment: I've added the `solution-verification` tag to this question.

Comment: Why don't use Schroeder-Bernstein: $f:\Bbb N\times \Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ is $f(a,b)=2^a3^b$, injective by FTA. The map $g: \Bbb N\to \Bbb N\times \Bbb N$ is $g(a)=(a,1)$ is obviously injective.

Comment: It is not clear what do you want verified. This is Goedel's proof.

Comment: @markvs That's a truly simple proof I should've thought about... Thank you for the comment! But I still want my proof to be verified and I want to get some comments about it :)

Comment: @markvs It's particularly because I've not yet followed the proof of the S-B theorem though I'm aware of its existence.

Comment: You mean [this function](https://www.cantorsparadise.com/cantor-pairing-function-e213a8a89c2b)? Cantor's pairing.

Comment: @markvs No from Cantor himself. Not Gödel.

Comment: Yes, Cantor of course. Gödel had a more complicated numbering.

Answer (score 5):

All the details are in the Wikipedia page for this [Cantor's pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function). It even derives an inverse.

But IMO $f(n,m)=2^{n-1}\cdot (2m-1)$ is a simpler bijection from $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$ ($\Bbb N=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$) (from my high school days). It's based on the simple observation that every number is a power of $2$ (possibly $2^0=1$) times an odd number in a unique way.

Comment: Thank you for the nice reference and advice! I derived an inverse too though :)